# How to disable CMD + E to eject?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

I have a MacBook Air, I want to disable the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut to eject because I want to assign it to another application and I really don't need to eject anything as I don't have a CD drive.

I've searched in the keyboard preference but that shortcut is not there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Karabiner**](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Disable ⌘E</name>
    <identifier>DisableCMDE</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::E, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::VK_NONE
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```